# access common phone abilities from an iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios

So I am trying to write a multi-purpose Iphone app. This app needs to access **and use** the following: texting and voicemail!

I do not want a log of texts and some form of the audio of voicemail, **I want to have an app that can set voicemails and I want to have the same app text people who do not have the app (by using their numbers).**

I looked for the past hour to try and find how to be able to do those two things, but I had no luck. Maybe I am just missing something.

Can somebody here point me to the API for those, or a section somewhere on Iphone programming to access all the original phone content? I know it exists, I just can't find it!

**Feel free to include any code on implementation, although I do not require it for an answer to be marked correct**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set voicemail messages through the iOS SDK, and you definitely cannot log the numbers from incoming calls. Voicemail is under the domain of your service provider so Apple couldn't provide this functionality if they wanted to.

---

Per my comment below, if you need functionality like YouMail, you would have to implement it on your own server and use an iOS app as the interface.

As for sending text messages, the only way I know of that is acceptable in the App Store is by using [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668) and [MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009669) . To send texts without user interaction, you would have to use a private API, or again, your own server.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken, take a look at [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youmail-visual-voicemail/id308331524?mt=8). This app has good reviews and is able to set different voicemails for different people, etc. So this is clearly possible. And I don't need to log numbers from incoming calls, I never said that, I need to be able to text from the app to people with any kind of phone using their numbers, which would be given by the user/taken from contacts

Comment: YouMail does the work on their own servers, not with the iOS SDK. The iOS app is simply an interface. Also, I believe you have to use the Message UI framework to send texts, or again, use your own server.

Comment: Okay, so in short, I need to have my own server to deal with the voicemail stuff, but there is something called Message UI that I can use to send texts? If you update your answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I included everything in my answer.

Comment: Hi Woz, I'm also facing same problem of doing voice mail in iphone sdk. can you please help me ...